# Axis configurations not being applied. Some axis with fixed length

Tags: pgfplots

The code below best reproduces the issue.

```
\documentclass[multi=true, crop=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, textcomp}
\standaloneenv{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, arrows.meta, decorations.pathreplacing, calc, matrix, positioning, angles, quotes, babel, intersections}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, samples=5000,
axis lines=center, axis equal,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
enlarge x limits=false, enlarge x limits=false}
\begin{documment}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]%183
\xdef\ux{2}
\xdef\uy{1}
\xdef\vx{1}
\xdef\vy{2}
\pgfmathparse{\vy+\uy}
\xdef\sy{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathparse{\vx+\ux}
\xdef\sx{\pgfmathresult}
\begin{axis}[xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, xmin=0,xmax=4, ymin=0, ymax=4,  
extra y ticks={\uy, \vy, \sy}, extra y tick labels={$y_1$, $y_2$, $y_1+y_2$},
extra x ticks={\vx, \ux, \sx}, extra x tick labels={$x_2$, $x_1$, $x_1+x_2$}]
\addplot[-latex] coordinates {(0,0)(\ux,\uy)} node[midway,below]{$\overrightarrow{u}$};
\addplot[-latex] coordinates {(0,0)(\vx,\vy)} node[midway,above]{$\overrightarrow{v}$};
\addplot[dashed] coordinates {(0,\vy)(\vx,\vy)(\vx,0)};
\addplot[dashed] coordinates {(0,\uy)(\ux,\uy)(\ux,0)};
\addplot[-latex] coordinates {(0,0)({\ux+\vx},{\uy+\vy})} node[pos=0.7,above left]{$\overrightarrow{u}+\overrightarrow{v}$};
\addplot[dashed] coordinates {(\ux,\uy)({\ux+\vx},{\uy+\vy})};
\addplot[dashed] coordinates {(\vx,\vy)({\ux+\vx},{\uy+\vy})};
\addplot[dashed] coordinates {(0,{\uy+\vy})({\ux+\vx},{\uy+\vy})({\ux+\vx},0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{documment}
```

[image]

The x axis should start with 0, but is starting with something else. I tried setting `axis lines=center` inside the `axis` environment too, but without effect.
At another plot, the fixed length is the y axis, and I don't know why. There are some plots (I belive around 10) with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**
You can just set `xmin=0.8`. Also replace `\begin{documment}` and `\end{documment}` with `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

**Input**

```
\documentclass[multi=true, crop=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, textcomp}
\standaloneenv{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, arrows.meta, decorations.pathreplacing, calc, matrix, positioning, angles, quotes, babel, intersections}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, samples=5000,
axis lines=center, axis equal,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
enlarge x limits=false, enlarge x limits=false}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]%183
\xdef\ux{2}
\xdef\uy{1}
\xdef\vx{1}
\xdef\vy{2}
\pgfmathparse{\vy+\uy}
\xdef\sy{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathparse{\vx+\ux}
\xdef\sx{\pgfmathresult}
\begin{axis}[xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, xmin=0.8,xmax=4, ymin=0, ymax=4,  
extra y ticks={\uy, \vy, \sy}, extra y tick labels={$y_1$, $y_2$, $y_1+y_2$},
extra x ticks={\vx, \ux, \sx}, extra x tick labels={$x_2$, $x_1$, $x_1+x_2$}]
\addplot[-latex] coordinates {(0,0)(\ux,\uy)} node[midway,below]{$\overrightarrow{u}$};
\addplot[-latex] coordinates {(0,0)(\vx,\vy)} node[midway,above]{$\overrightarrow{v}$};
\addplot[dashed] coordinates {(0,\vy)(\vx,\vy)(\vx,0)};
\addplot[dashed] coordinates {(0,\uy)(\ux,\uy)(\ux,0)};
\addplot[-latex] coordinates {(0,0)({\ux+\vx},{\uy+\vy})} node[pos=0.7,above left]{$\overrightarrow{u}+\overrightarrow{v}$};
\addplot[dashed] coordinates {(\ux,\uy)({\ux+\vx},{\uy+\vy})};
\addplot[dashed] coordinates {(\vx,\vy)({\ux+\vx},{\uy+\vy})};
\addplot[dashed] coordinates {(0,{\uy+\vy})({\ux+\vx},{\uy+\vy})({\ux+\vx},0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

**Solution 2:**
The real problem here is caused by the fact that you demand the axis to be equal. So you can also just remove `axis equal,` instead of changing the value of `xmin`.

Comment: My intention with `axis equal` was to have both axis with the same scale. How do I accomplish that?